Horror movie where the ending the woman gets pushed into a dark hole with a weird creature
All I remember in the beginning is a guy/girl trapped in a room and dirt comes pouring in and they suffocate. I think the main character moves into an apartment or weird building, with sketchy neighbors. Near the ending I think she tries to check what is inside this (water tank?) with some rope and bucket, and when she does, someone pushes her into the hole and she ends up in this dark small cave, and some person/monster is down there that feeds on people. There may also possibly another character she ended up trusting that is apart of the weird family, a guy, that pushes her down.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give?

"Dark Water" stars Jennifer Connelley in an apartment with sketchy neighbors, and the title element taking over her apartment when her daughter is with her estranged husband.  She searches for her daughter's missing playmate in a water tank..."The Dark" with Sean Bean ends as the mother in that film finds herself in a dark cave with a sinister figure. Two films addressing different plot points of your one request, but is either possible?

You might want to seperate these two movies into individual answers to make it possible for people to assess and possibly accept each one separately.
